# Laravel 5.5 Request Validations

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5.5

I have a login functionality from Web and also from API. I have created one Request file where I have written rules for this. For web, it is working perfectly and given output as expected but when I use it in API controller it redirects me to the login page, it should return JSON response.

One more thing, I want to add extra parameter "status" as it is failed or succeeds.

Here is my code
Request File

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ];
    }
```

API controller

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $response = array();
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $response['status'] = false;
        $response['message'] = $validator->messages();
        return Response::json($response);
    }

    try {
        $username = trim($request->username);
        $password = trim($request->password);

        $isAuth = $this->userRepository->login($username, $password);
        if ($isAuth) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $response['status'] = true;
            $response['message'] = Lang::get('custom.auth_success');
            $response['user_detail'] = $user;
        } else {
            $response['status'] = false;
            $response['message'] = Lang::get('auth.failed');
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $response = array();
        $response['status'] = false;
        $response['message'] = Lang::get('custom.something_wrong');
    }
    return Response::json($response);
}
```

and Web controller

```
 public function checkAuth(UserAuthenticate $request)
{
    try {
        $username = trim($request->username);
        $password = trim($request->password);
        $isRemember = false;
        if (isset($request->remember) && $request->remember == 'on') {
            $isRemember = true;
        }

        $isAuth = $this->userRepository->login($username, $password, $isRemember);

        if ($isAuth) {
            return redirect('programs');
        } else {
            return redirect('login')->withInput()->withErrors(['username' => Lang::get('auth.failed')]);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return redirect('login')->withInput()->withErrors(['error' => Lang::get('custom.something_wrong')]);
    }
}
```

Route/web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function () {
    Route::get('login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'Front\UserController@login']);
});
```

Route/api.php

```
Route::post('user/authenticate', 'API\UserController@login');
```

I looked for the solutions but didn't found anything

Comment: What authentication mechanism are you using for your API routes? Can you show us your api routes?

Comment: @user3574492, I update my question and added route file code for both  web and api

Comment: do you use passport for authentication

Comment: @afsalc, Yes. But that routes I have added in API middleware. Login route is not in API middleware

Comment: please share complete code of `public function login(UserAuthenticate $request){}` ?

Comment: @C2486, I added code in question, Please check

Comment: you are not doing proper authentication from `api.php` please read passport for the same. also `api.php` is stateless dont' use `Auth` will not work here.

Comment: @C2486, It is working code. Because of passport, I can use Auth in API. Only i don't want to rewrite Validations and want to use Request for both web and api

Comment: Then you can use only `web.php`  with prefix `api` instead `api.php` route

Comment: in api use extends request not form request for the validator

Comment: @C2486 he can't use the same validator, because the web validator extends FormRequest and that return html. Two validators are necessary, there is no way around it.

Comment: @Indra : he just need to return html and json conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: if you want to use extends Request for both validators do the web validation through ajax

1. Since you're using passport you already have the token so you can skip login
2. For api your validator needs to extend Request instead of FormRequest

You can't use the same validator, because the web validator extends FormRequest and that return html. Two validators are necessary, there is no way around it.

> ```
> use App\Http\Requests\Request;
>   class YourApiRequest extends Request
>   {
>       /**
>        * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
>        *
>        * @return bool
>        */
>   public function authorize()
>   {
>       return true;
>   }
>
>       /**
>        * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
>        *
>        * @return array
>        */
>       public function rules()
>       {}....
> ```

In your normal web request you would have

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
 class YourWebRequest extends FormRequest
 {
 /**
* Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
*
* @return bool
*/
 public function authorize()
 {
 // only allow updates if the user is logged in
 return \Auth::check();
 }

 /**
* Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
*
* @return array
*/
 public function rules()
 {....
```

3. In Handler.php you need to add something to the render method (if you return json from your api)

   If you do not prefix your routes with **api/** then figure out how to check if you are in api

> ```
> if (strpos($prefix, 'api') !== false) {
>             if ($exception instanceof ValidationException) {
>                 return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => $exception->errors(), 'data' => null], 200);
>             }
>             return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => $exception->getMessage(), 'data' => null], 200);
>         }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to over ride the **Laravel form request validation**'s **`failedValidation()`** method.

```
public function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    //wantsJson() that checks Accept header of the request and returns TRUE if JSON was requested.
    if ($this->wantsJson()) {
        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json(["response" => [
            'msg'    => $validator->errors()->all(),
        ]]));
    }
}
```

[Not tested on api calls]